# How I can seen my created page of site on my OpenShift?

Tags: java, spring, git, tomcat, netbeans

I try create site on Java with Spring help on OpenShift.

I did some actions:
-Registered an account at OpenShift
-Set it
-Created application 'myapp' with 'Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)' Cartridge
-Cloned it by git
-Edited myapp by NetBeans(made simple index.jsp page which can saw by NetBeans Tomcat Local Server 8.0).
-Pushed this project to OpenShift server by 'git push'(there's this data with changes on the server at this moment)
-Deployed on the server(used 'gear deploy' command)

And now I want seen my page on server but can seen only it:
myapp-masakra.rhccloud.com

what I have to do or change?

Comment: I see page with blue background. Isn't this right? 
Well, first you have to wait until server perform full restart (unless you enable hot-deploying - I don't know if this works in Tomcat).
Second, you may have to clean your web browser cache.

Comment: must be this text "Hello! This is the default welcome page for a Spring Web MVC project.

To display a different welcome page for this project, modify index.jsp , or create your own welcome page then change the redirection in redirect.jsp to point to the new welcome page and also update the welcome-file setting in web.xml." on white background and no more

Comment: I restarted my app and nothing changed